# PHP script calling itself

Tags: php

I red there's a limit for a PHP script to be executed and I wanted to know if the timer of max_execution_time starts again from 0 if I find a way for the script to call itself with a parameter appended once finished execution. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. Why didn't you just tried?

Comment: Yes it would as it's a new instance, but unless you spawn and release the process it will be sent SIGHUP when the initial script dies. Far better to increase execution time with [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: @lorenzo-s: because at the moment I don't know how to do it, so I asked if it was even possible, before trying. I did not ask HOW to do it, anyway.

Comment: @DaveRandom: ok, I'll investigate further, thanks.

Comment: Food for thought, the timer is reset when the shutdown handler is run :) note that web servers may also have a time out for web processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do this at the top of the script:

```
ini_set("max_execution_time","300");
```

Where `300 or any integer value is the number of seconds the script should be allowed to run for`
**REMEMBER: It must be at the top of the script**

Comment: Is there any possibility this would not have effect?

Comment: Nope, it will always take effect. So long as you place it at the top of the script!

Comment: Don't forget to vote up my answer if it helps you...Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks very much!   :-)  It seems at the moment I can't vote up, but when I can I come back to vote up.

Comment: Please leave off the quotes i.e. ` ` they're a typo. Will remove them now

Comment: "Is there any possibility this would not have effect?" ; Yes - there is one possibility, as the documentation at php.net says: This function has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode. There is no workaround other than turning off safe mode or changing the time limit in the php.ini.

Comment: On a shared hoster, they might restrict the execution time and you might not be able to change the time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it creates a new instance each time.

You can increase your execution time with `set_time_limit()`

Example :

Your script lasts 20s but you need 20s more, use : `set_time_limit(20)`

But if you want to increase your max execution time, change your `php.ini` value : `max_execution_time`

Comment: It seems this server (for some unknown reason) doesn't accept the set_time_limit

Comment: change your `php.ini` value : `max_execution_time`

Comment: Problem is I simply can't: it is a shared hosting and you can't modify the PHP.ini.